# How to use async/await inside event handlers of a "use client" file in Next JS?

Tags: next.js

I'm rendering a page which uses states to store data and it contains several event handlers that needs async/await because it contains fetch function. How would I go about this?

I've read about using useEffect, but how would I integrate it inside a handler in this case? Is it possible?

Here's a snippet of one of my page.jsx file:

```js
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";

const CarouselSectionPage = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState();
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);

  const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files) {
      const image = e.target.files[0];
      new Compressor(image, {
        quality: 0.6, // 0.6 can also be used, but its not recommended to go below.
        success: (compressedResult) => {
          setCompressedFile(compressedResult);
          setFile(compressedResult);
        },
      });
    }
  };

  const handleUploadClick = async() => {
    if (!compressedFile) {
      return;
    }
    try {   
      setUploading(true);
      await createCarousel({
        variables: {
          input: {
            image: {
              bucket: "testbucket",
              key: secret.key,
              region: "us-1",
            },
            ),
          },
        },
      });
      setUploading(false);
      setTimeout(() => {
        navigate(0);
      }, 2000);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error uploading file: ", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
         type="file"
         id="images"
         accept="image/*"
         onChange={handleFileChange}
         required
         style={{ display: "none" }}
      />
      <button disabled={uploading} onClick={() => handleUploadClick()}>
    </div>
  )
};
```

The code above of course doesn't work because "use client" and async/await would conflict with one another. All inputs are appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You just forgot `const handleUploadClick = async() => {` ? Or you want to implement 
fetch function inside `useEffect`?

Comment: Yes my bad, the correct one is `const handleUploadClick = async() => {`. I was playing around with my code before and forgot to add it back in, hehe.

I want to explore all possible methods of making the code work. So whether using useEffect or other methods I'd appreciate all inputs.

Comment: To use async/await inside event handlers of a "use client" file in Next.js, you need to ensure that your event handlers are declared as asynchronous functions and then use await where necessary. const handleUploadClick = async() => {

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement `async/await` inside `useEffect`, go like this. `useEffect` itself only accepts a normal callback without `async`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const yourFetch = async() => {
        const res = await fetch(xxxx)
        // Do something to res.
    }
    
    yourFetch();
}, [Deps])
// Deps depend on you. If you want to run at only first render, empty the array.
```

Answer (score 0):

To use async/await inside event handlers of a "use client" file in Next.js, you must ensure that your event handlers are declared as asynchronous functions and then use await where necessary. Here's a general example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleClick = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await fetchData();
        console.log(result);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You call an async function from a sync function:

```
<button disabled={uploading} onClick={() => handleUploadClick()}>
```

Try this:

```
<button disabled={uploading} onClick={handleUploadClick}>
```